# Vuetify carousel both next item and previous item from same direction

Tags: vue.js, vuetifyjs3

Trying to create a carousel with vuetify. Normally the next item and the previous item slide in from opposite direction. In my carousel I want next and previous item to slide in from same direction (both from left / both from right). I have experimented with [reverse-transition](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#eNpdkMEOgjAMhl9l2dmxkxeDJj6HeFhGxeLYlnUQjfHdHaAyvDTt9yd/2//05BS0PHpfDD3wHS8jdN6oCIfKMlYOQnk/tdOgnY0KLYQPmqEKricwP7aiApPjojA2iIsL+4ojQ8u2Fc+1dEtSrjF62kmpazteFfHyaKnQrpPYqQZIJu+aZO30jYrWN2sP7QYIOQiQAIGIQVnCiM6mHWSwBnHPYO5yKOXfB8vDmfINZkSrZEYyB1fKLFD+2tjemKmc3zp+d4Q=) but failed.

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-container>
      <v-carousel>
        <v-carousel-item
          v-for="i in 5"
          src="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/cards/docks.jpg"
          cover
          reverse-transition="slide-x-transition"
        ></v-carousel-item>
      </v-carousel>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `reverse-transition="v-window-x-transition"` (or `transition="v-window-x-reverse-transition"`). Though it is missing in the list of Vuetify transitions ([here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/transitions/)), it is what v-window uses internally (see [code](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/72e5319ac2792c5a90bce79669c2c1a8a65a24ad/packages/vuetify/src/components/VWindow/VWindow.tsx#L123-L128)).

Here it is in a [playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#eNpdkcFOwzAMhl/F5FIQZKlAXKp2iBtvwIEirepSFimJo8TtkKa9O0kLLN0lij/bf+w/HycWfC9endtMo2QVq0kapzuS29YC1BPvnJuvc9CjpU5Z6X/RAjuPY5D6n60oV1HxkgGY+IC+aZkCZeG5ZXmuisPE1O5A5EIlhFN9GM3GHZAwiMeyFE9l+eI7u0fT7O7VurvHSfoceBlBkJxiR1Ck0EbxiR9V7D/y74znQttaXI1/2TbL/LmS0MqWRBbXapG5GcPQe+UIgqRxMVUZh57gFCcd4AyDRwNF/IgilaeFbCAw4QuaVHFbvEmtEd7R6/1NcZceWCSjGDs/2FHr+fj8AeNplYw=)